# dont have access in docs while using streamBuilder. Firebase Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

when i try to use snapshot i dont have access to the document please check code you will understand.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chat').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
          ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 2,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => BubbleNormal(
                text: snapshot.data. // in here  i can't do snapshot.data.docs,
              ),
            );
    });
}
```

1[please check the image more helpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ng4n.png)

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the documentation on [monitoring realtime changes](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes), you'll want to declare the type of your `StreamBuilder`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chat').snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      ...
```